# Is $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{72}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{18} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{48}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{72}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{18} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{48}$?

**Proof**: $\mathbb{Z}_{18} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{48}$ has an element of order $lcm(18, 48) = 144$, however, the highest order an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{72}$ can have is equal to $lcm(12, 72) = 72$.

Is this enough to conclude that there is no isomorphism between these two groups?

Comment: Does homomorphism preserve order as well? @Mastrem

Comment: No, just consider the trivial homorphism $f:G \mapsto H$, $f(g)=e_H$ for all $g \in G$.

Comment: Isomorphisms preserve order, so yes, it should be enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough if you are explicit about it:

> The order of $(1,1) \in \mathbb{Z}_{18} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{48}$ is $144$ but every element of $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{72}$ has order at most $72$.